# "All there is are cells" as a philosophical school of thought

Tags: reference-request, terminology, philosophy-of-biology, atomism, natural-philosophy

Like atomists since Demokrit and Lucretius believe that all matter is made out of atoms, biologists since Schleiden and Schwann believe that all living matter is made out of cells.

But since atomism started as a philosophical doctrine which later was given a proper name I am not aware of a philosophical doctrine like "cellularism" or so - considering the philosophical consequences of this world view.

If there is such a school of thought - taking the idea serious to its extreme that "all there is are cells *and their interactions*" - **under which name** does it sail? (One proponent of this school may have been Richard Dawkins and his selfish genes.)

---

Whether atoms or cells have substructures (or are true indivisibles) is not the matter of this question.

Comment: Generally speaking in philosophy of mind (and body), body is usually treated as same as matter, most ancient philosophers were especially interested in souls or some substantial forms, such as the famous Aristotle's Hylomorphism which is a major application of his substance theory...

Comment: There is atomism in ancient Greek and Indian Philosophies. Richard Dawkins is a philosopher in his own mind.

Answer (score 1):

Atoms have substructure though, like quarks. Atoms as we consider them were only confirmed in the early 1900, with Ernst Mach still insisting matter was fundamentally continuous in 1903 (a lesser known accomplishment of Einstein was the first accurate estimate of an atomic size, from his analysis of Brownian motion). And now our fundamental theory is of fields (QFT).

You might say 'atomism' is a kind of synonym for reductionism, the idea the complex world we see has a fundamental strata or layer, that once fully known can account predictively for phenomena at all larger scales.

Biology simply isn't like that. Knowing what cells are where, leaves a huge amount out of what can be predicted. To some extent it's about what is tractable, a lump of relatively homogenous atoms, even though there are of the order of 10^23 atoms (Avogadro's number), can be dealt with statistically. Whereas biology exposes us to the '[Unreasonable ineffectiveness of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreasonable_ineffectiveness_of_mathematics)' outside of physics. But most of what is important about organisms isn't defined by the properties of the fundamental unit, but by how they are linked together, by large-scale structure, like say  neural connections in the brain.

It is characteristic of biology to have [emergent](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties-emergent) wholes who's qualities are better and more tractable predictors than the states of their substructure (where sensitivity to initial conditions means even only quantum uncertainty will rapidly make total information about atoms useless for prediction).

Answer (score 0):

The atoms of Greek atomism were nothing like the atoms of modern atomic theory, so there is no sense other than historical in which Greek atomism is any kind of precursor to modern atomic theory. What I mean by that is that the beginning of modern atomic theory may have been partly inspired by Greek atomism, but they quickly left behind anything characteristic of that philosophy.

Modern cell theory originated in microscopic observation. To my knowledge nothing remotely similar was ever proposed before those observations were made.

## Addendum:

The atoms of Greek atomism had the following properties:

1. They were eternal--never created or destroyed.
2. They had no parts.
3. All of an atom's properties came from it's physical shape. For example, if something tasted sour it was because it had atoms with sharp points in it (I never understood how the atomists reconciled this with "no parts").
4. Atoms are rigid objects that interact with other atoms by direct mechanical action. There was no action at a distance.

By contrast modern atoms

1. Are constructed and destroyed.
2. Have parts.
3. The binding properties of atoms are affected by the shape of the electrical fields around them, but there is nothing like the analogy influences postulated by the Greeks.
4. Are not rigid and interact with other atoms by electromagnetic forces.

Comment: "Were **nothing** like" - how can you say that? I would understand "were not exactly like". But don't Democrit's ideas have quite a lot in common with modern ideas?

Comment: I've added an addendum. Other than being the smallest particle of a particular element, and the consequences of that, they have nothing in common.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. But that's about modern atomic theory. [Dalton](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095658664) (1803) who stands somehow between Demokrit and modern physics had ideas more similar to pre-Socratics - and please note that stable isotopes are also not destroyed (under normal circumstances).

Comment: Greek atoms were not just physically indestructible, but metaphysically indestructible. They were timeless; that is, there was no way for them to change in any way (this goes with them not having parts). I know that Dalton postulated atoms as a way to explain chemical  binding, rather than as a metaphysical substrate, but I'm not familiar enough with his work to know how much he separated from the Greeks. By the early twentieth century, though, there was no similarity between Greek and modern atoms.